# Confluence XML-RPC: Set the "creation" date

Tags: python, xml-rpc, confluence

I am trying to migrate some existing blog entries into our confluence wiki using XML-RPC with Python. It is currently working with such things as title, content, space etc but will not work for created date.

This is what was currently attempted

```
import xmlrpclib

proxy=xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('<my_confluence>/rpc/xmlrpc')
token=proxy.confluence1.login('username', 'password')

page = {
    'title':'myTitle',
    'content':'My Content',
    'space':'myspace',
    'created':sometime
}

proxy.confluence1.storePage(token, page)
```

`sometime` is the date I want to set to a time in the past. I have tried using Date objects, various string formats and even the date object returned by a previous save, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would try to store the existing content as actual blog entries in Confluence, then you could use the "publishDate" parameter:

```
import xmlrpclib
import datetime

proxy=xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('<my_confluence>/rpc/xmlrpc')
token=proxy.confluence1.login('username', 'password')

blogpost = {
    'title' : 'myTitle',
    'content' : 'My Content',
    'space' : 'myspace',
    'publishDate' : datetime.datetime(2001, 11, 21, 16, 30)
}

proxy.confluence1.storeBlogEntry(token, blogpost)
```

The XML-API for pages ignores the "created" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` because type will not match directly. Hope this works.

```
new_sometime = datetime.strptime(sometime, '%Y-%m-%d')
page = {
    'title':'myTitle',
    'content':'My Content',
    'space':'myspace',
    'created':new_sometime
}
```

Comment: I have tried various string formatting options and they dont seems to work. I think the problem might be that confluence is overwriting the created time to when it is actually created, which kind of makes sense I guess...

Comment: when u will fetch old value it will in string format and u want 2 overwrite then u need to convert in datetime format.

Comment: first print and chack new_sometime. are u getting it properly. may be if your datetime format is diff then also possible u can not do it

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesnt work. I have treid many different formats, and as I said in the question, I even tried the actual date object returned from a previous save (which is set by confluence)